# Can't make ribbon edges stay on top

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index

So, I modified a wordpress tabs widget so that I could make it look like in the image I attached, only that I have one problem.

I can't make the ribbon edges stay on top of the website layout. 
I have a demo of what I've done so far [here.](http://roxanat.com/demo/zibibbo/?page_id=12)

So I added this code to show the images:

```
#wp-tabs-1 .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav:before{
    content: url(../images/l-corner.png);
    width: 47px;
    height: 43px;  
    position: absolute;    
    left: -5em;    
    z-index: 999;
}

#wp-tabs-1 .ui-tabs-nav:after{
    content: url(../images/r-corner.png);
    width: 47px;
    height: 43px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5em;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I tried all the positioning combinations with the z-index that I could, and nothing seems to work, to make the ribbon edges stay on top.[image: ribbon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're hidden by `.grid { overflow: hidden }`. Change it to `.grid { overflow: visible }` or simply remove it and it should work.

Comment: GENIUS :D, it works!!! Thanks a lot. It seems that I have to study my overflows more :)